# Nginx configuration to host a web app and a static website

Tags: nginx

Right now I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy to server my Node.js App.

This is the configuration in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`file

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    # Use certificate and key provided by Let's Encrypt:
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    # Pass requests for / to localhost:8000:
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I can access this web app by typing example.com or example.com:8000.

I also uploaded a static website file in this path `/home/ftp/single`. Initially I would like to make this path accessible ( then I can visit the static website via example.com/home/ftp/single )

I could not do it, my compromised solution is to then add a server block in the `default` file:

```
server {
listen 2222;
 root /home/ftp/single;
}
```

so Now if I type example.com:2222 I will visit the static file.

**However I am not very satisfied with this. My desired situation is when I visit example.com/static/, I will access the static file as if I type example.com:2222 under the current setting**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have files in `/home/ftp/single` and want to access them via `http://example.com/home/ftp/single`, you need the following additional `location` block:

```
location /home/ftp/single {
    root /;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

This one tells nginx that requests to normalized URI paths starting with `/home/ftp/single` are served so that the root folder is filesystem root, and then the `try_files` tells nginx to look up the files specified in the URI (string after the domain name for virtual server).

The `index` directive tells nginx which file to show when the request points to a path without a filename.

However, having a `root` directive set to point to filesystem root is not a good idea, since it might expose other system files to remote visitors.

I would recommend this approach:

```
location /single {
    root /home/ftp;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Then, accessing `http://example.com/single` will show the file at `/home/ftp/single/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to know the domain name to be sure. However, my guess is you're forwarding from http to https, and there's no https server available because you commented it out.

If you "curl -i http://example.com" your domain over you'll probably get a response back telling you "301 redirect to https://example.com".

If you don't please update your question to give more information, including

- curl http and https website
- access log for those curls (not just random logs, correlate them for us)
- error logs for those curls (not just random logs, correlate them for us)

Of course it could be a DNS problem, but you haven't told us anything about your DNS.

Comment: Currently I am not assigning any domain to this IP address. But If I still curl -i http://example.com I 'd get HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently. This is because I have another host hosting the same app and I have my example.com DNS to that another host.  But can I still get this done without having a domain name? i.e When I visit IPaddress/website/example/index.html I 'd get the static file. At this moment if I do IPaddress:8000 I can visit the app because it listens to the 8000 port.

Comment: Your comment is confusing. Please edit your question to provide more complete information about your environment - what servers you have, what they're doing, on what port, etc. I'm also not sure if you want to redirect or proxy. You haven't defined your setup or your desired outcome properly.

Comment: However, if you have this server listening by IP, and you want to forward it to another server, you need to make sure the 301 redirect you return points at that server. Right now you're forwarding to 443 on the same server. eg "return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;".

Comment: Shouldn't I stop forwarding to 443 when I have all those setting commented out? Is it the problem why the IPaddress/website/example/index.html inaccessible?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't described your environment, current situation, or desired situation properly. Voting to close, but if you can edit your post and add the information it will be left open or re-opened.

Comment: Sorry I am actually quite new to Nginx and the whole server setting. So at times I have some difficulties to get the whole picture and explain my situations. By environment do you mean the server operating system? It is Ubuntu. I also updated the question hopefully it is clearer...